# Equality comparison between multiple variables

Tags: c#, comparison, operators, equality

I've a situation where I need to check whether multiple variables are having same data such as

```
var x=1;
var y=1;
var z=1;
```

I want to check whether x==1 and y==1 z==1 (it may be '1' or some other value). instead of this, is there any short way I can achieve same such as below

```
if(x==y==z==1)
```

Is this possible in C#?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

KennyTM is correct, there is no other simpler or more efficient way.

However, if you have many variables, you could also build an array of the values and use the IEnumerable.All method to verify they're all 1. More readable, IMO.

```
if (new[] { v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9, v10 }.All(x => x == 1))
```

Instead of

```
if(v1 == 1 && v2 == 1 && v3 == 1 && v4 == 1 && v5 == 1 && v6 == 1 && v7 == 1 && v8 == 1 && v9== 1 && v10 == 1)
```

Comment: So for an OR (||) statement you could just do .Any instead of .All?

Answer (score 37):

```
if (x == y && y == z && z == 1)
```

is the best you can do, because

`y == z` evaluates to a boolean and you can't compare `x` with the result:

```
x == (y == z)

|    |

int  bool
```

I would do this:

```
public bool AllEqual<T>(params T[] values) {
    if(values == null || values.Length == 0)
         return true;
    return values.All(v => v.Equals(values[0]));    
}

// ...

if(AllEqual(x, y, z)) { ... }
```

Answer (score 30):

If you just want to testif x == y == z you can use:

```
var allEqual = new[] {x, y, z}.Distinct().Count() == 1;
```

If you want to test if they're all equal to 1, add 1 to the set:

```
var allEqual1 = new[] {x, y, z, 1}.Distinct().Count() == 1;
```

or use `All` as in fencliff's answer.

Comment: +1. brilliant. I'd accept this answer. It's not how much you know, it's all about how well you know whatever you already know. My answer looks silly in front of this.

Comment: Thing to watch out for in large sets this is O(N log N) while the accepted solution is O(N).

Comment: Just adding on top of @MichaelAnderson, performance speaking, how will that Distinct() perform if you have an enough large set with different values?

Answer (score 10):

```
if (x == y && y == z && z == 1)
```

There are no other simple or more efficient ways.

Comment: Sorry to say that I'm not expecting this answer as even I know I can achieve it with such 3 expression check. My question might not be clear enough. I wanted to achieve this in single expression as I stated above without And operator. Anyway thanks for clarifying that there is no simpler way.

Answer (score 5):

For integral types, what about:

```
int x = 3, y = 3, z = 3;

if((x & y & z & 3) == 3)
  //...have same data
```

for testing any *non-zero* value.
It would need more checks to make this a re-usable function. But might work for inline checks of non-zero equality, as the OP described.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a nice little recursive solution that works with all types.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = 4, y = 4, z = 4;
        Console.WriteLine(4.IsEqualToAllIn(x, y, z).ToString());
        //prints True

        string a = "str", b = "str1", c = "str";
        Console.WriteLine("str".IsEqualToAllIn(a, b, c).ToString());
        //prints False
    }
}

public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static bool IsEqualToAllIn<T>(this T valueToCompare, params T[] list)
    {
        bool prevResult = true;
        if (list.Count() > 1)
            prevResult = list[0].IsEqualToAllIn(list.Skip(1).ToArray());
        return (valueToCompare.Equals(list[0])) && prevResult;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public static bool AllSame<T>(List<T> values)
{
    return values.Distinct().Count() == 1;
}

public static bool AllDifferent<T>(List<T> values)
{
    return values.Distinct().Count() == values.Count;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this extension:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool EqualsAll<T>(this T subject, params T[] values) =>
        values == null || values.Length == 0 || values.All(v => v.Equals(subject));
}
```

Then call it like so:

```
if(1.EqualsAll(x, y, z))
```

Answer (score 2):

XOR might work for you, e.g. given:

```
var x=1;
var y=1;
var z=1;
```

Then

```
x ^ y ^ z == 0
```

Is true

-edit-
If you want to check if all values are the same and their value is 1, use:

```
x ^ y ^ z ^ 1 == 0
```

Comment: If you choose to use this in an if statement, surround the ^ (XOR) operators with parentheses as: if((x ^ y ^ z ^ 1)==0)

Comment: @Jazimov why?.....

Comment: @minseong otherwise you get a compiler error

Comment: this does not really work as `x` and`y` will be evaluated to a value (perhaps to `0` if they're equal) and then this value will  be XOR'ed with `z`

Answer (score 1):

Slight variation on the excellent answer given by jevakallio above. See if myValue is equal to any of the values in a list (in the array):

```
if (new[] { 10, 11, 12 }.Any(x => x == myValue))
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually i don't have to the time to code, but an extension method with linq like this

```
public bool EqualsToAll<T>(this T element, IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    if(element == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(element);

    foreach(var item in source)
    {
        if(!element.Equals(item)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

should make it.

**Warning:** This code was not tested, nor written within an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = 1;
var y = 1;
var z = 1;

if (AllEqual(1, x, y, z))    // true
if (AllEqual(2, x, y, z))    // false
if (AllEqual(x, y, z))       // true

var a = 1;
var b = 2;
var c = 3;

if (AllEqual(a, b, c))       // false

// ...

public static bool AllEqual<T>(params T[] values)
{
    if (values == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("values");

    if (values.Length < 1)
        throw new ArgumentException("Values cannot be empty.", "values");

    T value = values[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!value.Equals(values[i]))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I adapted Mau's solution into an extension method.  It would be nice if they added this to the framework for all value types.

```
public static class IntegerExtensions
{
    public static bool EqualsAll(this int subject, params int[] values)
    {
        if (values == null || values.Length == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return values.All(v => v == subject);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is how I did this:

```
Debug.Assert(new List<int> { l1.Count, l2.Count, l3.Count, l4.Count }.TrueForAll(
  delegate(int value) { return value == l1.Count; }), "Tables have different size.");
```