# checking whether four boolean variables have equal value, non-obvious?

Tags: c#, boolean

I have four bool variables, say :

```
bool a=true;
bool b=false;
bool c=true;
bool d=false;
```

then I want to check that those four are equal. However;

```
Console.WriteLine(true == false == true == false);
true
```

Why is this happening? I think it is because of evalution order of an equation, which goes from left to right :

```
((true == false) == true) == false
(false == true) == false
false == false
true
```

then What is a proper way to check whether all N>2 boolean variables are equal?

Comment: Your assumption is correct. If the same operator is used throughout an expression... operator precedence means nothing.. they are all the same..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An obvious way would be to pair them and use .Equals() instead of ==

---

Check this alternative, it could be what you want - [Equality comparison between multiple variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254839/equality-comparison-between-multiple-variables)

Answer (score 7):

```
if(a==b && a==c && a==d)
```

If you have variable number of bools not only 4

```
var bools = new bool[] { a, b, c, d };
var areAllEqual = bools.Skip(1).All(b=>b==bools[0]);
```

Comment: +1 oops, you have already mentioned about the array (Also you can use a also instead of bools[0] since you already have the value )

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could add put them in an array and then use the All operator

```
yourboolarray.All(x=>x == a) // compare with any a,b,c,d
```

Answer (score 1):

you could consider using bitwise methods for this

where by the integer representation of the bools would equal 0 or 15 (or any value depending on number of bits)

may require some code restructuring though

Comment: What?  No.  If you're going to convert them to ints, you may as well just count them.  But really, values should be left in their 'natural' types, not cast like this.