# a == b == c triple comparison in C# vs Python

Tags: c#, python

How would you translate this python code into c#

```
l = [True, False]
for a in l:
    for b in l:
            for c in l:
                    print(a, b, c, a==b==c)
```

(Which outputs this)

```
True True True True
True True False False
True False True False
True False False False
False True True False
False True False False
False False True False
False False False True
```

Into something like

```
void Main()
{
    List<bool> l = new List<bool> (){true, false};
    foreach(var a in l)
    {
        foreach(var b in l)
        {
            foreach(var c in l)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(a.ToString()+" "+b.ToString()+" "+c.ToString()+" "+(a==b==c).ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which unfortunately doesn't work the same way and outputs this:

```
True True True True
True True False False
True False True False
True False False True
False True True False
False True False True
False False True True
False False False False
```

Comment: Well the python `a==b==c` transforms to `a==b and b==c` , why not use that directly?

Comment: This other post has a similar answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254839/equality-comparison-between-multiple-variables

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python has [chained comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) so `a == b == c` is taken to mean:

```python
(a == b) and (b == c)
```

In C# `a == b == c` is evaluated as:

```csharp
(a == b) == c
```

To translate Python's `a == b == c` to C# use

```
a == b && b == c
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem gets obvious when you change the list to this:

```
List<int> l = new List<int> { 1, 0 };
```

Now, you get an error that you cannot use the `==` operator on operands of the type `bool` and `int`. But you are doing `int == int == int`. So the only explanation for the error is that one of the comparisons is already evaluated before the second comparison is evaluated. And that’s exactly what happens here.

The expression `a == b == c` is equivalent to `(a == b) == c` in C#.

Python is special here in that it expands `a == b == c` to `a == b and b == c`. So the correct way to express that in C# is `a == b && b == c`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine(a.ToString()+" "+b.ToString()+" "+c.ToString()+" "+(a==b && b == c).ToString());
```

Comment: The question was a direct request for translation.