# Multiple Variable if Statement C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im brand new to C# and am trying to figure out how to add another variable to this if statement. It currently checks the database to see if a user has an an account level of 2 and if so it restricts certain actions. I would like it to check for account level 3 as well and preform the same action. So basically: `if (uType==2 && 3)`, but im not sure this is the correct format.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
int uType = getUlevel(Accountid.Text);
if (uType==2) // I want it to check if uType is 2 or 3 here.
{
    transferOK.Text = "2";
    return;
}
```

Comment: `if(uType==2 || uType==3)`

Comment: A bit overkill for just two options, but also check the 'switch' statement: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254839/equality-comparison-between-multiple-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to start would be a beginner C# tutorial. Any book/video would cover such basics. [Here's a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lisiwUZJXqQ)
 that covers the essentials in about an hour.

To answer your question:

```
if (uType==2 || uType==3)
{
     transferOK.Text = uType.ToString();
     return;
}
```

Note that you might want to change your action based on the value of uType. That's why I changed your `"2"` literal to `uType.ToString()`.

Good luck, and study hard.

Comment: Thank you for the references! I will check out this video now.

Comment: @Void Hope it helps! He goes pretty fast, so pause and fiddle as you follow along (and *do follow along*). There is also the [Learn Programming](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/) subreddit. They probably have a ton of helpful links and references, although perhaps not specific to C#. Note that C# is just a language, and that learning a language is separate from learning to program. Once your done what that video, head to the subreddit and read the sidebar. Long road ahead, but stick with it and go one step at a time.

Comment: Appreciate the wise words, Ill do my best!

Answer (score 0):

`&&` is "and". Or is `||`.

You'd do it like this:

```
if (uType == 2 || uType == 3)
{
```

Comment: You should not answer this kind of question, Because is a duplicated question, he must learn to search

Comment: @xsami At an early enough stage, they're so lost that they can't even begin to guess what to search for.

Comment: I really understand your opinion. But I think that you would help him more just commenting a reference to this question where he can realize his error. That also help StackOverflow to not keep duplicated questions.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thanks for the help! For everyone, commenting about a duplicate, yes Ed is right, I wasn't exactly sure what to search for. The things I did search did not return results I was looking for.

Comment: @xsami That's a reasonable point. CaptainMarvel's answer, with a link to a (good, I hope) tutorial, is a good one though. And the duplicate doesn't address OP's confusion between && and ||.