# How to make 3 items follow a specific condition, only if user specifies that they match the same value?

Tags: c#

I'm wondering how to make 3 items follow a specific condition (for instance they can be summed), only if user specifies that they match the SAME DYNAMIC value that user enters? Otherwise, they don't follow that condition. As:

```
if((thing1 && thing2 && thing3).Equals(SAME DYNAMIC VALUE)
sum = thing1 + thing2 + thing3;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equality comparison between multiple variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254839/equality-comparison-between-multiple-variables)

Answer (score 1):

You can only do `thing1 && thing2 && thing3` if they are all boolean which in your case does not seem to be the case.  In your case you can do the following

`if(thing1 == thing2 && thing2 == thing3)`

BEWARE of objects! If you have objects then change to 
`if(thing1.Equals(thing2) && thing2.Equals(thing3)`

Answer (score 0):

You need something like:

```
if(thing1.Equals(SAME DYNAMIC VALUE) && thing2.Equals(SAME DYNAMIC VALUE) && thing3.Equals(SAME DYNAMIC VALUE))
    {
         sum = thing1 + thing2 + thing3;
    }
else{
       // don't perform calculation
    }
```

Note, the sum will only calculate if all of the conditions are true.